# how to set default radio button comparing database value in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, radio-button

Did a lot of research but couldn't find a working solution.Here's my question.
I have a list of radio buttons named branchlist and i am fetching a value named branch from database. Now i wish to set the radio button as checked whose value is equal to the value of branch. Here is my code:

```
<%
                ArrayList<String> branchlist = new ArrayList<String>();
                branchlist.add(0,"Computer Engineering");
                branchlist.add(1,"Information Technology");
                branchlist.add(2,"Electronic & Telecom");
                branchlist.add(3,"Instrumentation Engineering");
                branchlist.add(4,"Mechanical Engineering ");
                branchlist.add(5,"Civil Engineering");

                for(int i=0;i<branchlist.size();i++){
                    //System.out.println(branchlist.get(i)+"="+branch);
                    if(branchlist.equals(branch)){%>  <--- branch is the string value I am fetching from database.
                        <input  type="radio" name="branch" value="<%=branchlist.get(i)%>" checked="checked" ><%=branchlist.get(i) %><br>
                    <% }else {%>
                    <input type="radio" name="branch" value="<%=branchlist.get(i)%>" ><%=branchlist.get(i) %><br>

                <%}

                    }%>
```

Comment: Not related, but Please don't use scriptlets. It's a bad practice now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this:

```
<%
                ArrayList<String> branchlist = new ArrayList<String>();
                branchlist.add(0,"Computer Engineering");
                branchlist.add(1,"Information Technology");
                branchlist.add(2,"Electronic & Telecom");
                branchlist.add(3,"Instrumentation Engineering");
                branchlist.add(4,"Mechanical Engineering ");
                branchlist.add(5,"Civil Engineering");

                for(int i=0;i<branchlist.size();i++){
                    //System.out.println(branchlist.get(i)+"="+branch);
                    if(branchlist.get(i).toString().equals(branch)){%> 
                        <input  type="radio" name="branch" value="<%=branchlist.get(i)%>" checked="checked" ><%=branchlist.get(i) %><br>
                    <% }else {%>
                    <input type="radio" name="branch" value="<%=branchlist.get(i)%>" ><%=branchlist.get(i) %><br>

                <%}

                    }%>
```

Comment: hey yes.. branchlist.get(i) did work.. silly of me.. thanx :)